# trying to get the resources.name joined to advisorresources

Tags: azure-resource-graph, azure-advisor

Using Azure Resource Graph Queries and a kusto query, trying to get resources.name of the   advisorresources properties field in json of resourceMetadata.resourceId, joined on the resource id.

**Kusto Query**

```
advisorresources 
  | extend jProp = parse_json(properties)
  | extend iResourceId = tostring(jProp.resourceMetadata.resourceId)
  | join kind=inner (resources | project id, rname=name) on iResourceId
  | project rname
```

**Error Message**

- Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp =
  2022-10-18T15:57:41.3840226Z, correlationId =
  285bf458-6caa-41e5-891e-646166764ada. (Code:BadRequest)
- Details: Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the
  Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying.
  (Code:InvalidQuery) 'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar
  expression named 'iResourceId' (Code:Operator_FailedToResolveEntity)
  Failed to resolve join attribute on the right side (Code:Default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right side of the `join` doesn't include a column named `iResourceId` - it only includes the columns `id` and `rname`:

`resources | project id, rname=name`

try replacing the above with:

`resources | project iResourceId=id, rname=name`